# Software to handle incoming phone calls and reply via sms

Tags: sms, twilio, phone-call

My company has got a new project upcoming and i need software that can take a phone call, have an automated response and then reply to client via sms. (something similar like Twilio (http://www.twilio.com/api) but it needs to be used in South Africa...

Anybody have an idea?
Thanks

Comment: While it doesn't answer the IVR part of the question, you could use [Nexmo](http://www.nexmo.com/) (I do some developer evangelism there) to handle sending the SMS.

Comment: the sms part of the whole program is easy to do and already configured... we just need the Automate Voice System to be able to launch the sms part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until Twilio finally gets around to supporting South Africans, you'll have to settle for one option: https://www.tropo.com/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u look at this?
[Skypekit](http://developer.skype.com/public/skypekit)

Skype doesnt have any country boundations.

There's as option for skypekit for desktop programs also u can have an embedded chip if you want.

Comment: @kartik_anand Unfortunately that will not work... an example of what i would like to do: User is at a certain location with a specific land line and makes a call to the server from that land line, server then verifies the user and location and sends confirmation sms to the user's cellphone

Comment: u can make calls to skype easily (u can buy a skype number on which users can make calls) and location can also be identified with ease..check this..http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/features/allfeatures/online-number/

Comment: ok... so i get an online number, then what? how do i get Skype to launch an external app and send data back to the client via sms? how do i automate skype so that there is no human at the "Skype Side" of the line?

Comment: I found a program that might work [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) now all i have to do is learn it from scratch.... :(

Comment: they'll provide you with a SDK..and u can make desktop applications according to your needs..you'll have to create an account there first.and since u'll be learning..why not try skype SDK which is atleast reliable

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the user is calling into and automated self service application (i.e. IVR system) and not a live person.  There are ways to handle both, but for this discussion I will assume that the receiving end of the call is a machine. I would use [Voxeo Prophecy](http://evolution.voxeo.com/) to handle taking the call, performing the verification, and sending the SMS message. You have the option with Prophecy to use Voxeo's hosted service or you can use an on-premise solution. You can [download a two port version for free](http://www.voxeo.com/prophecy/) to try it out for an on-premise solution or [sign up for a free developer account](http://evolution.voxeo.com/) to try their hosted solution.  Their hosted solution has international support but you will want to verify with their excellent tech support team to make sure that they support your area. Just drop them a question in the developer forum and they will respond quickly. You will find that Prophecy is much easier to setup as opposed to Asterisk and you will get free and excellent tech support from Voxeo's team even before you purchase anything.

The development language for this IVR system is open standards called [VoiceXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/) and [Call Control XML (CCXML)](http://www.w3.org/TR/ccxml/).  These are web based standards and you generally have to use other web based languages to perform operations outside of the standard IVR and telephony domain; for example integrating to an SMS gateway. If you are an ASP.NET developer I would recommend checking out the [open source project called VoiceModel](http://voicemodel.codeplex.com/) which simplifies developing VoiceXML applications using ASP.NET MVC.  There are also many Java based tools and libraries available for VoiceXML development as well.

Voxeo has a third solution for your application, which is [Tropo](https://www.tropo.com/home.jsp). This is more like the Twilio solution you already investigated. This runs on the same Voxeo hosted infrastructure but again you will want to verify that it is supported in your area. Tropo is strictly hosted and there is no on-premise solution.  The reason I prefer VoicXML/CCXML is that it is an open standard supported by a multitude of IVR vendors and therefore you do not get vendor lock-in. Also the CCXML provides excellent call control capabilities for more advanced applications like outbound dialing, conferencing, and call progress analysis.

To send your SMS message you will need to integrate with an SMS Gateway service. Most of them have simple REST type API's to integrate with your voice/telephony application. Voxeo also has an excellent SMS gateway service called [SMSified](http://smsified.com/), but it looks like they currently only support the US. You might want to check [SMSGateway](http://www.smsgateway.ca/). I have used their service as well and it does have international support, but you will want to verify with them that they support your area. There are a lot of SMS Gateway services out there. Just Google "SMS Gateway".